# div has ID and class, but class doesn't apply to the div

Tags: html, css

I have this simple html/css code below. 
When I try to change the font size in my "welcome" class, it doesn't actually apply the font size, background color, font weight etc on any of the content in the div.

Could I please get an explanation as to why this happens. The DIV itself has a ID and class.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .welcome {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 50%;
  font-style: oblique;
   background-color: yellow;
  }


  a:hover {
   font-size: 500%;
  }

  #greeting {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
   text-align: left;
  }

  p {
   color: green;
  }
  </style>

</head>


<body>
<div id="greeting" class=”welcome”>

 Sample Text
 <p>Thank you for coming here!</p>
 <p>Welcome to <a href=”ltu.html”>La Trobe</a></p>
 <p>Thank you for coming here!</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you're using `”` charachter for class, use simple `"` or `'` and it'll work fine, it's also the same for your anchor's href

Comment: Question voted to be close as the issue was caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: CURSE OF COPYPASTER :D

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have copied the code from somewhere, 
the quotes you have used are not the correct ones.

Instead of

```
class=”welcome”
```

it should be

```
class="welcome"
```

(same for other parts of code)

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong character to define your class, instead use double or single quote as below,

```
<div id="greeting" class=”welcome”><!--This is incorrect-->
<div id="greeting" class="welcome"><!--Use this--> 
<div id="greeting" class='welcome'><!--Or this one-->
```

Comment: <!-- HTML COMMENT -->

Comment: @invissible Now it okay :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes (') instead of double quotes ("). That seems to be the problem.